# Getting specific value in a cookie that has multiple value

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies, decode

So I have this cookie that I wanted to get. But it has multiple values that is not yet decoded and I only wanted few of them.

```
HttpContext cookie_context = HttpContext.Current;
var cookie_user = cookie_context.Request.Cookies["cookie"] != null ? HttpUtility.UrlDecode(cookie_context.Request.Cookies["cookie"].Value) : "";
```

**Result[raw] is:**

```
%7B%22userId%22%3A%223578975542237785%22%2C%22pageviewId%22%3A%225539528752116331%22%2C%22sessionId%22%3A%225164692360282986%22%2C%22identity%22%3A%22d4e19ed9-d66b-48cc-a6ff-68340200d3b7%22%2C%22trackerVersion%22%3A%224.0%22%2C%22identityField%22%3Anull%2C%22isIdentified%22%3A1%7D
```

**Result[decoded] using chrome show url decoded is:**

```
{"accId":"3578975542237785","viewId":"5539528752116331","sessionId":"5164692360282986","userid":"d4e19ed9-d66b-48cc-a6ff-68340200d3b7","Version":"4.0","Field":null,"isIdentified":1}
```

**Result[decoded] in compiler when I use HTTPUtility.UrlDecode:**

```
"{\"accId\":\"3578975542237785\",\"viewId\":\"5539528752116331\",\"sessionId\":\"5164692360282986\",\"userid\":\"d4e19ed9-d66b-48cc-a6ff-68340200d3b7\",\"Version\":\"4.0\",\"identityField\":null,\"isIdentified\":1}"
```

What I only wanted to get the **accId** and **userid** values and store it in variable for code condition purpose but I cant get it.The code that I use always returns null. Check below.

**Example of the code that I used:**

```
HttpContext val_cookie_context = HttpContext.Current;
var val_cookie = val_cookie_context.Request.Cookies["cookie"]["accId"];
```

Comment: That is JSON. Deserialize it. https://quicktype.io/csharp

Comment: how do I deserialize it? Is there a way I can do it without using linq or json deserialization? it became like that after I user HttpUtility.UrlDecode in the server side.

Comment: `how do I deserialize it?` Did you click the link? `Is there a way I can do it without using linq or json deserialization?` Why do you want to avoid json deserialisation?

Comment: It seems the current project does not support it because I tried Json.Deserialization by adding it in model and it wanted to add a dll. And due to restrctions I am not allowed to do it.

Comment: `And due to restrctions I am not allowed to do it.` What are the restrictions _exactly_? JSON deserialisation should work OOTB.

Comment: Compiler Error CS0012. It seems that the net library is old. @mjwills

Comment: Please share a [mcve] of your attempt. Are you able to use JSON.NET ?